# Implementation of interface within state machine

Tags: state-machine, hdl, verilog

This particular example is verilog, but my question is more about the state machine structuring, which would be relevant to both VHDL and verilog.

So if I have a state machine, this one is fairly simple:

```
always@(posedge m_axi_clk) begin        
if(m_axi_resetn == 0) begin
  current_state   <= S_IDLE;
end
else begin
  if ((ps_axi_busy == 0) && (ps_wr_en_i == 0)) begin
      case(current_state)
    S_IDLE: current_state <= S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG;
    S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG:
      if (config_done == 1)
        current_state <= S_WAIT_FOR_DMA;
      else
        current_state <= S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG;
            ...
    S_HALTED:         current_state <= S_HALTED;
    default:          current_state <= S_HALTED;
      endcase 
  end 
end
end
```

If I want to perform, for example, a BRAM write triggered from the state machine state, I usually split the processes up, so I'll duplicate the entire process and then do the following:

```
always@(posedge m_axi_clk) begin        
if(m_axi_resetn == 0) begin
  ps_wr_addr_i  <= 0;
  ps_wr_data_i  <= 0;
  ps_wr_en_i    <= 0;
end
else begin
  if ((ps_axi_busy == 0) && (ps_wr_en_i == 0))
    case(current_state)
      S_IDLE:
    begin       
        ps_wr_addr_i  <= `INPUT_NEXT;
        ps_wr_data_i  <= ones;
        ps_wr_en_i    <= 1;
    end
      S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG:
    begin
        ps_wr_addr_i  <= 0;
        ps_wr_data_i  <= 0;
        ps_wr_en_i    <= 0;     
        if (config_done == 1) begin
          ps_wr_addr_i  <= `INPUT_DATA;
          ps_wr_data_i  <= ones;
          ps_wr_en_i    <= 1;
        end
    end
          ...
      default:
    begin
        ps_wr_addr_i  <= 0;
        ps_wr_data_i <= 0;
        ps_wr_en_i <= 0;
    end
    endcase // case (current_state)
  else begin
      ps_wr_addr_i  <= 0;
      ps_wr_data_i <= 0;
      ps_wr_en_i <= 0;      
  end // else: !if(ps_axi_busy == 0)
end // else: !if(m_axi_resetn == 0
```

I used to do one big process, where I merge everything together, but that gets big fast for multiple interfaces and multiple states. Then it's also difficult to sift through the signals to check that each write is in the right place.

I usually take out all the states where writes don't occur and bunch them up together under `default`. This works nicely for small state machines, although if I do a write on a state edge, then I will need to maintain that condition through both processes. For example, I only switch out of `S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG` (and do the write) when `config_done` is asserted. This condition is now in twice, and I have to change it in two places (something I'd like to avoid, if possible).

I've also been thinking about creating a delayed state signal and doing an edge detect on that in order to trigger certain BRAM writes, this allows the `config_done` to trigger the state switch, and then that edge triggers the writes. This is great for writes on state switch edges, but I can't do the same thing for writes that are in the middle of states.

There's also the asynchronous option:

```
assign ps_wr_addr_i = ((current_state == S_IDLE)             && (ps_axi_busy == 0))                          ? `INPUT_NEXT:
                      ((current_state == S_WAIT_FOR_CONFIG)  && (config_done)        && (ps_axi_busy == 0))  ? `INPUT_DATA:
                      0;
...
```

I prefer this from a readability/elegance standpoint, but due to the timing implications (no longer pipelined), I don't really use it that often. Also, once again the `config_done` check needs to be maintained in multiple places.

I understand that there are subtle variations in the behaviour of each of these three, so small adjustments will probably need to be made for similar behaviour overall. Also I think it depends on what is needed at the time as far as pipelining goes. However, I'm more interested behind the principal behind these writes.

Is there a better way of doing this, or is this it? How do I handle scaling this state machine for a more complicated protocol where writes are necessary perhaps at the beginning, middle, or end of a state? Do I make separate states for that, or do I use edge triggers/if statements? How do write this in an elegant way and stop it from just running away into an abomination of a state machine?

**TL;DR** I usually use a state machine as a way of setting up the framework of what gets done when, and then all the other signals revolve around that. I'm struggling to consolidate this "macro" framework with the "micro" details that involve timing multiple writes during one state. Am I thinking about this wrong and can I be using a state machine in a better way?

Comment: Added tag. I know some people .... who know verilog really well. I will see if I can get them to have a look through this. FPGA-based wiring is otherwise a pretty slow section in Code Review.

Comment: @rolfl Thanks. Now that I've discovered this side of the SE world, I'll probably hang around and contribute some answers to the HDL stuff when it comes up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all questions on codereview, some of the comments below is just opinion  and there are always several ways of doing things.  However my personal style preferences have evolved over many years of debugging my own (and other people's) code!

### First some style comments on the code itself:

```
always@(posedge m_axi_clk) begin
```

Unless you're stuck with very out-dated tools it's better to use `always_ff @(posedge m_axi_clk) begin`.

```
case(current_state)
  S_IDLE:
begin
```

Personally I find your placement of `begin` a bit inconsistent - same line for `if` statements but a newline for `case` entries?  The indentation makes it slightly harder to follow.

```
    ps_wr_addr_i  <= 0;
    ps_wr_data_i <= 0;
```

Do you actually need to drive the `addr` and `data` lines low when not doing a write?  Often they're qualified by the `en` so this generates superfluous logic.

### General comments

> If I want to perform, for example, a BRAM write triggered from the state machine state, I usually split the processes up, so I'll duplicate the entire process

The "duplicate the entire process" raises a red flag here.  Code duplication is *generally* wrong and should be avoided if there's a better way to do things.

> I used to do one big process, where I merge everything together, but that gets big fast for multiple interfaces and multiple states. Then it's also difficult to sift through the signals to check that each write is in the right place.

So here we get to the crux of the problem.  Your current style is making a single process unwieldy, but splitting into multiple processes forces you to make compromises.

My advice would be to avoid multiple processes unless necessary.  It's very difficult to debug code where many processes are interacting.  It also becomes hard to maintain - when adding code where does it go?  What if I need a new synchonisation flag to communicate between processes?  Even if it starts off well, over time it will grow into bad code!

My advice would be to use the following style:

- Only have a single `case` statement for your state machine
- Stick to a single process if possible

  - Easier to debug, modify, maintain
  - Will also improve simulation speed (marginally)
  - Only resort to 2 processes if you need to drive outputs asynchronously
- Collect related signals together in structures (or interfaces)
- Factor conditions that are used multiple times outside the state-machine
- Re-factor common actions to the end of the process

  - use blocking assignments to indicate which actions to take

The main goal is to simplify the state machine - ideally you want it to read naturally.  Here is an example showing some of these in action:

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic [31:0]                data;
    logic [7:0]                 addr;
    logic                       en;
} write_t;

write_t                         write;

assign some_condition = (bing & bong) || (ding & ~dong);

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin

    // Defaults
    if (write_accepted)
        write.en <= 1'b0;

    case (state)
        IDLE: begin
            if (some_condition)
                state           <= WAIT_FOR_CONFIG;
        end

        WAIT_FOR_CONFIG: begin

            if (some_condition)
                state           <= ANOTHER_STATE;
            else if (some_other_condition)
                state           <= THE_OTHER_STATE;
            else begin
                state           <= SOMETHING_ELSE;
                write.addr      <= that_address;
                do_write        = 1'b1;             // Blocking assignment
            end

        end

        ...

    endcase


    // Common actions
    if (do_write) begin
        write.en        <= 1'b1;
        ...
    end

end
```

Comment: Why is it better to use begin on a new line after the always?

Comment: @StaceyAnne That's just a formatting artefact from in-line markup.  The improvement is moving from `always @` to `always_ff @` which tell the tools more about your intentions and allow them to perform additional checks for you.

Comment: I believe always_ff is a systemverilog construct, not a verilog one?

Comment: Yes, it's SystemVerilog, but plain Verilog is effectively deprecated having been merged into the SV standard.  Only stick with Verilog if have very good reason to stay decades behind (i.e. forced to use some very old tools).

Comment: The most recent version of Xilinx ISE doesn't have SystemVerilog Support, I'd hardly say ISE is very old. My client wants verilog-only, so I don't have much choice.

Comment: ISE has been maintenance only for 6 months, it's effectively deprecated by Vivado which has been around for over 2 years and has reasonable SV support.  For new designs you should consider switching from ISE to Vivado, but as ever the client is always right :)

Comment: Vivago only supports Gen7 and up, though. Spartan/virtex 6 and below still only are develop-able in ISE, So you're stuck if you want to use a device that's more than a couple years old.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that I've since switched to SV and it's been great! Thanks for your feedback in this answer.